# addAnnotations method only places last annotation from Array

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have problem adding annotations to mapView. I had success with this code:

```
func placeAnnotations() {

    for _ in placeDetails {

        let multipleAnnotations = MKPointAnnotation()
        multipleAnnotations.title = place.address
        multipleAnnotations.subtitle = place.phone
        multipleAnnotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.lat, longitude: place.lng)
       mapView.addAnnotation(multipleAnnotations)

    }

}
```

Problem is, it is not conforming to my Place class, thus not showing custom Title, Subtitle and MKAnnotationView. This is code inside viewDidLoad(), where I'm trying to put all the annotations, but it keeps adding only last one. I understood that it overrides all the previous ones from array, but haven't found any other way/method to implement.

```
  var placeDetails = [Place]()
    var places = [Place]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            downloadPlaceID {
                for obj in places {
                    place.downloadDetails(input: obj.placeId, completed: {
                        self.placeDetails.append(obj)
                     //self.placeAnnotations()
   self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.placeDetails)
                    })

                }
            }
        }
```

And this is my class with all the data conforming to MKAnnotation
protocol, and functions, downloadPlaceID() and downloadDetails()

```
 class Place: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        var placeId: String!
        var vicinity: String!
        var phone: String!
        var workHours: Bool!
        var lat: Double!
        var lng: Double!
        var address: String!

        var subtitle: String? {
            return phone
        }

        var title: String? {
            return address
        }



        var _placeId: String {
            if placeId == nil {
                placeId = ""
            }
            return placeId
        }

        var _vicinity: String {
            if vicinity == nil {
                vicinity = ""
            }
            return vicinity
        }

        var _phone: String {
            if phone == nil {
                phone = ""
            }
            return phone
        }

        var _workHours: Bool {
            if workHours == nil {
                workHours = false
            }
            return workHours
        }

        var _lat: Double {
            if lat == nil {
                lat = 0.0
            }
            return lat
        }

        var _lng: Double {
            if lng == nil {
                lng = 0.0
            }
            return lng
        }

        var _address: String {
            if address == nil {
                address = ""
            }
            return address
        }



        init(place: [String:Any]) {

            if let ids = place["place_id"] as? String {
                self.placeId = ids
            }

            if let vicinities = place["vicinity"] as? String {
                self.vicinity = vicinities
            }

            self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 0.0)

        }

        func downloadDetails(input: String, completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {

            let details = "\(detailsBaseURL)\(detailsPlaceId)\(input)\(detailsKey)\(detailsSearchAPIKey)"

            Alamofire.request(details).responseJSON { response in
                let result = response.result


                if let dictionary = result.value as? [String:Any] {

                    if let result = dictionary["result"] as? [String:Any] {

                        if let phoneNumber = result["formatted_phone_number"] as? String {
                            self.phone = phoneNumber
                        }

                        if let  geometry = result["geometry"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let location = geometry["location"] as? [String:Any] {
                                if let latitude = location["lat"] as? Double {
                                    self.lat = latitude
                                }
                                if let longitude = location["lng"] as? Double {
                                    self.lng = longitude
                                }

                                self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.lat, self.lng)

                            }
                        }

                        if let openingHours = result["opening_hours"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let openNow = openingHours["open_now"] as? Bool {
                                self.workHours = openNow
                            }
                        }

                        if let addressComponents = result["address_components"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                            let longName = addressComponents[1]["long_name"] as? String
                            let shortName = addressComponents[0]["long_name"] as? String

                            self.address = "\(longName!),\(shortName!)"
                        }
                    }
                }
                completed()
            }
        }
    }






 func downloadPlaceID (completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {

        let placeURL = URL(string: nearbyURL)

        Alamofire.request(placeURL!).responseJSON { (response) in
            let result = response.result

            if let dictionary = result.value as? [String:Any] {
                if let results = dictionary["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {

                    if let status = dictionary["status"] as? String  {
                        if status == "OK" {
                            for obj in results {
                                place = Place(place: obj)
                                places.append(place)
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("jede govna")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            completed()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some odd mixing of variable names and concepts here that makes your code somewhat hard to understand.

As an example, assigning a variable you call `vicinities`, plural, to an attribute called `vicinity`, singular. Or not separating your downloadDetails function from your data model.

That aside, it looks to me like you're unnecessarily adding your MKAnnotations many times to your map, by adding your array of `[MKAnnotation]` to your map in each loop.

I suspect you've done this because you've made it hard for yourself to know when the whole array is done updating its details.

As a quick fix, I'd suggest changing your `downloadDetails` function to call the `completed` function with the place you've just downloaded details for. Here's a really simplified, but working, version of what you are trying to do. First your `Place` class:

```
class Place: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    override init() {
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0)
    }

    func downloadDetails(completed: @escaping (Place) -> Void) {
        // Instead of downloading details we are just creating random positions
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(arc4random_uniform(50)), CLLocationDegrees(arc4random_uniform(50)))

        // Return the object you've just built
        completed(self)
    }
}
```

Now in your view controller, here I am starting with an array of 50 `Place` objects, getting the details for them and placing them on the map:

```
var places = [Place]()
for _ in 1...50 {
    places.append(Place())
}

for place in places {
    place.downloadDetails(completed: { (placeWithDetails) in
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(placeWithDetails)
    })
}
```

This results in the map being populated with 50 random places:

[image: iPhone Simulator showing 50 random annotation points on a mapview]

Comment: Hi, it is still adding only the last member of Array..As i understood going through other posts, it is adding one annotation at a time, while removing the previous one. Even if it put all annotations every time it goes through a loop, i would expect it to leave all annotations from array the last time it goes through a loop...if I go with func placeAnnotations() it works fine, but i do not know how those newly created instances inside func  to conform to MKAnnotation..maybe you could help me in that direction..

Comment: I've updated my example above to the simplest possible working example.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Used your variation, and divided my Place class into two classes, the other conforming to MKAnnotation. After populating array belonging to other class, called Details, i managed to get all the annotations and conformed them to desired image and custom description.